# GetAdaptersInfo Get Media Status and Detect WiFi Type

Tags: winapi, adapter, ethernet

I am using code similar to this one:
[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917%28VS.85%29.aspx)

1. How do I get media status (connected or disconnected)?
2. How do I know if adapter is wireless type?

Prashant

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Native WiFi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706556%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). (For XP requires SP2/3, min server 2k8)

You can list enabled adapters with `WlanEnumInterfaces`.

You can fetch state with `WlanQueryInterface` with `wlan_intf_opcode_interface_state` to request the state in a `WLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES` struct.

An alternative are the [MSNDIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ndis/archive/2011/04/06/exploring-ndis-s-wmi-classes.aspx) WMI Classes.